# Removing array item by value

Tags: php, arrays

I need to remove array item with given value:

```
if (in_array($id, $items)) {
    $items = array_flip($items);
    unset($items[ $id ]);
    $items = array_flip($items);
}
```

Could it be done in shorter (more efficient) way?

Answer (score 435, accepted):

It can be accomplished with a simple one-liner.

Having this array:

```
$arr = array('nice_item', 'remove_me', 'another_liked_item', 'remove_me_also');
```

You can do:

```
$arr = array_diff($arr, array('remove_me', 'remove_me_also'));
```

And the value of `$arr` will be:

```
array('nice_item', 'another_liked_item')
```

Comment: Only if you have control of the variable. If you received it as a reference this method is unusable.

Comment: No, it *does* works with referenced arrays, the `array_diff` function is non-destructive, it returns a new array.

Comment: You miss my point, if you got an array by reference and wanted to remove an item from it, you couldn't with this method.

Comment: @srcspider why not? `$referenced = array_diff($referenced, $items_to_remove);`

Comment: $referenced is now pointing to a new array, the array you wanted to change still has the old values.

Comment: @srcspider well, you tell me what's going on here then... http://codepad.org/11ZhiFP0

Comment: my bad; php's variable aliasing gimmick always trips me over >.>

Answer (score 37):

I am adding a second answer.  I wrote a quick benchmarking script to try various methods here.

```
$arr = array(0 => 123456);
for($i = 1; $i < 500000; $i++) {
    $arr[$i] = rand(0,PHP_INT_MAX);
}

shuffle($arr);
$arr2 = $arr;
$arr3 = $arr;

/** 
 * Method 1 - array_search()
 */
$start = microtime(true);
while(($key = array_search(123456,$arr)) !== false) {
    unset($arr[$key]);
}
echo count($arr). ' left, in '.(microtime(true) - $start).' seconds<BR>';

/** 
 * Method 2 - basic loop
 */
$start = microtime(true);
foreach($arr2 as $k => $v) {
    if ($v == 123456) {
        unset($arr2[$k]);
    }
}
echo count($arr2). 'left, in '.(microtime(true) - $start).' seconds<BR>';

/** 
 * Method 3 - array_keys() with search parameter
 */
$start = microtime(true);
$keys = array_keys($arr3,123456);
foreach($keys as $k) {
    unset($arr3[$k]);
}
echo count($arr3). 'left, in '.(microtime(true) - $start).' seconds<BR>';
```

The third method, `array_keys()` with the optional search parameter specified, seems to be by far the best method.  Output example:

```
499999 left, in 0.090957164764404 seconds
499999left, in 0.43156313896179 seconds
499999left, in 0.028877019882202 seconds
```

Judging by this, the solution I would use then would be:

```
$keysToRemove = array_keys($items,$id);
foreach($keysToRemove as $k) {
    unset($items[$k]);
}
```

Comment: I think array_search is much more readable code than using the array_diff method. Upvote

Comment: @zombat I wonder if order has anything to do with the results. It is possible that shuffle put the value we are searching for either closer to the front or end. Other than that... +1

Answer (score 34):

How about:

```
if (($key = array_search($id, $items)) !== false) unset($items[$key]);
```

or for multiple values:

```
while(($key = array_search($id, $items)) !== false) {
    unset($items[$key]);
}
```

This would prevent key loss as well, which is a side effect of `array_flip()`.

Comment: won't work if $id is first array element, better this way:

if ( ($key = array_search($id, $items)) !== false) unset($items[$key]);

Answer (score 17):

to remove `$rm_val` from `$arr`

```
unset($arr[array_search($rm_val, $arr)]);
```

Answer (score 8):

The most powerful solution would be using [`array_filter`](http://php.net/array_filter), which allows you to define your own filtering function.

But some might say it's a bit overkill, in your situation... 

A simple `foreach` loop to go trough the array and remove the item you don't want should be enough.

Something like this, in your case, should probably do the trick :

```
foreach ($items as $key => $value) {
    if ($value == $id) {
        unset($items[$key]);
        // If you know you only have one line to remove, you can decomment the next line, to stop looping
        //break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Try [array_search()](http://www.php.net/array_search)

Comment: I just read the documentation, and it recommend to use array_keys() to find all the keys associated to a value.

Comment: @Savageman - Agreed.  I ran a quick benchmark and `array_keys()` seems to perform better than `array_search()` for this task.

Answer (score 6):

Your solutions only work if you have unique values in your array

See:

```
<?php
$trans = array("a" => 1, "b" => 1, "c" => 2);
$trans = array_flip($trans);
print_r($trans);
?>
```

A better way would be unset with [array_search](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php), in a loop if neccessary.

Comment: you are right, but in this particular case I'm pretty sure that values are unique :)

Answer (score 5):

w/o flip:

```
<?php
foreach ($items as $key => $value) {
    if ($id === $value) {
        unset($items[$key]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

```
function deleteValyeFromArray($array,$value)
{
   foreach($array as $key=>$val)
   {
      if($val == $value)
      {
         unset($array[$key]);
      }
   }
   return $array;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use array_splice function for this operation Ref : [array_splice](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-splice.php)

```
array_splice($array, array_search(58, $array ), 1);
```