# unset( ) not working PHP

Tags: php

I have tried many different ways but im not able to unset a variable from an array. I started with a string and exploded it to an array, now i want to remove Bill. Im i missing some thing? I have visited php.net and i, still stuck...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title></title>

</head>
<body>

<?php


$names = "Harry George Bill David Sam Jimmy";

$Allname = explode(" ",$names);

unset($Allname['Bill']);

sort($Allname);

$together = implode("," ,$Allname);

echo "$together";
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You've got an array of names as values, but you're trying to use the value as an `index`. It's looking for data at position `Bill`, which doesn't exist.

Comment: unset($Allname[2]) -> it's looking for index, not value

Comment: bill is the value in the array not the key of the array

Comment: `$key = array_search('Bill', $Allname); if ($key !== false) unset($Allname[$key]);`

Comment: *sidenote:* you can always use `print_r()` or `var_dump()` to debug.

Comment: Chek this answer by GarciaWebDev

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1883421/removing-array-item-by-value

Answer (score 19, accepted):

That is because ['Bill'] is the value of the array entry, not the index.
What you want to do is

```
unset($Allname[2]); //Bill is #3 in the list and the array starts at 0.
```

or see this question for a more detailed and better answer :

[PHP array delete by value (not key)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7225070/php-array-delete-by-value-not-key)

Comment: Thank every it makes scenes now..... I was able to accomplice what what i needed with the foreach loop.   Thanks for the link 1intello

Answer (score 1):

Because unset expect a key and not a value.

Bill is your value.

```
unset($Allname[2])
```

after your explode the array looks like:

```
array (

0 => 'Harry',
1 => 'George',
2 => 'Bill',
...
)
```

Comment: If i dont know the position of bill i would use a foreach?

Comment: there are several ways to do it. a foreach loop is possible but i would prefer `array_search()` to get the key of Bill.

`$key = array_search('Bill', $Allname);`

Answer (score 1):

`unset($arr['key'])` unsets the *key*. Your keys are `0`, `1` etc, not "Bill".

If you want to remove the *value* "Bill", it's easiest to do this:

```
$names            = 'Harry George Bill David Sam Jimmy';
$namesArray       = explode(' ', $names);
$namesWithoutBill = array_diff($namesArray, array('Bill'));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
You can unset by array key
unset($Allname[2]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes, it looks like an array but it can be a printed string of an array... - It happens to the best of us...

Or in any case check your array is really an array.
I know it sounds silly but sometimes after many hours of screen time , mistakes are made.

```
<?php

$MyArray = array('0' => 'this','1' => 'is','2' => 'an array');
echo is_array($MyArray) ? 'It Is an Array' : 'not an Array';

?>
```

This will output: It Is an Array.