# Remove values from php variable

Tags: php, mysql, content-management-system

How can I remove some values from `$sku` variable? It returns `2110`, `1630`, `4565`, etc. from DB.

Code:

```
$products = SProductVariantsQuery::create()->find()->toArray();

foreach ($products as $variant) {
$sku = $variant['Number'];
}
```

var_dump($sku) return this:

```
string(4) "2250" string(4) "2251" string(3) "428" string(3) "427" string(4) "2800" string(4) "2804"
```

Comment: Can you add a `var_dump()` of your variable so we can see how it's structured?

Comment: Also, please give your desired output...

Comment: please have a look                http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1883421/removing-array-item-by-value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an array with values you want to exclude before you do the foreach and then check if the value is in there:

```
// Exclude prod. no 427 and 2800
$exclude = array('427', '2800');

foreach ($products as $variant) {
    // Only set $sku if the Number is not in the exclude array
    if (!in_array($variant['Number'], $exclude)) {
        $sku = $variant['Number'];
    }
}
```