# Remove specific value of array

Tags: php

I want to remove specific value of array. this's my code:

**HTML**

```
<form action="" method="post">
<input type="text" name="user">
<input type="submit" value="Watch">
</form>
```

**PHP**

```
$user='';

if ( isset ( $_POST['user'] ) ) { $user = $_POST['user']; }

$dir = "images/".$user.'/';

$dh = opendir ( $dir );

while ( false !== ($filename = readdir( $dh ) ) ) {
    $files[] = $filename; 
}

$files = array_diff ( $files, array('.','..') );

$e = count($files);

for ( $i=0; $i<$e; $i++ ) { echo $files[$i]; }
```

**Output**

```
user/.
user/..
user/HTML.txt
user/CSS.txt
user/JavaScript.txt
```

i tried `array_diff()` to remove `'.'` and `'..'`.

i get noticed offset 0 on for value by latest WAMP.

and how to make **While** version to **For** version loop that use **opendir**, and **readdir**?

Comment: What is the desired output

Comment: possible duplicate of [Removing array item by value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1883421/removing-array-item-by-value)

Comment: Utkarsh : i want to remove `.` and `..`. but i get notice offset 0 on `For` **i** variabel value

Comment: `pc-shooter` : thanks for the tag. but the answer on that is already in my code. i get error noticed offset 0.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Delete an element from an array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/369602/delete-an-element-from-an-array)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

User If .. and condition no need to use array_diff

```
while ( false !== ($filename = readdir( $dh ) ) ) {
    if($filename != '.' && $filename != '..') {
        $files[] = $filename; 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

TBI's answer is recommended, for your particular case; it makes sense to never put it in the array in the first place. However, to match the title of your question, to remove an element from an array, you should use `unset`:

```
foreach($files as $key => $file){
    if($file == '.' || $file =='..'){
        unset($key);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `if()` condition, like -

```
while ( false !== ($filename = readdir( $dh ) ) ) {
    if($filename != '.' || $filename != '..') {
        $files[] = $filename; 
    }
}
```

Now, you dont need to use `array_diff`

Comment: `TBI` : theres wrong expression that in above codes. ||. it should be &&. thank you :)