# Remove if array contains string from another array

Tags: php, arrays

So the idea is to remove from one array a list of numbers of other array, but it's only removing the first one, any help to solve this will be appreciated.

```
$my_array = array("Sandra Loor,593984076233","Adrian,593998016010","Lucas,593999843424");


function myFilter($string) {
    $to_remove = array("593984076233","593998016010");
    foreach($to_remove as $remove)  {
        return strpos($string, $remove) === false;
    }

}

$newArray = array_filter($my_array, 'myFilter');

foreach ($newArray as $val){
    echo $val.'<br>';
}
```

Comment: can you give an example of output you expect plz

Comment: Possible duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2448964/php-how-to-remove-specific-element-from-an-array or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1883421/removing-array-item-by-value

Comment: @Amas the output I expect is only `Lucas,593999843424` instead I get `Adrian,593998016010
Lucas,593999843424`

Comment: Your `foreach` exits on the **first** loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your filter will always `return` from the first iteration of the loop.
This instead will return false if it finds the entry and at the end of the loop will return true (i.e. not found at all)...

```
function myFilter($string) {
    $to_remove = array("593984076233","593998016010");
    foreach($to_remove as $remove)  {
        if ( strpos($string, $remove) !== false )
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Another method is to use preg_grep to search the array for the items you want to remove, then use array_diff to remove them.

```
$my_array = array("Sandra Loor,593984076233","Adrian,593998016010","Lucas,593999843424");
$to_remove = array("593984076233","593998016010");

$to_remove = "/" . implode("|", $to_remove) . "/";
$match = preg_grep($to_remove, $my_array);
$filtered = array_diff($my_array, $match);

var_dump($filtered);
// Lucas,593999843424
```

https://3v4l.org/PZ4I6

---

You can also bunch it up to a one liner like this:

```
$my_array = array("Sandra Loor,593984076233","Adrian,593998016010","Lucas,593999843424");
$to_remove = array("593984076233","593998016010");

$filtered = array_diff($my_array, preg_grep("/" . implode("|", $to_remove) . "/", $my_array));

var_dump($filtered);
```